# MySQL Between Query not working for two time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written this MySQL query to filter data, I think in query works, if it get equal values but it **doesn't work for between values**. Please help me to sort out this issue..

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
        table_name 
    WHERE 
        job_date='" . $jobDateAfterFormat . "' 
        AND employee_id='" . $employee_id . "' 
        AND (
            start_time = '" . $start_time . "' 
            OR start_time BETWEEN '" . $start_time . "' AND '" . $finish_time . "' 
            OR finish_time='" . $finish_time . "' 
            OR finish_time BETWEEN '" . $start_time . "' AND '" . $finish_time . "')
```

The job_date use as a time stamp, start_time and finish_time use  18:30, 07:30 format.

Comment: This isn't just MySQL, there is also (I guess) PHP in it. If that's the case, use prepared statements.

Comment: Explain "it doesn't work".